# Where's the NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet?

Tags: nuget-package, nodatime

At [Latest API documentation](http://nodatime.org/unstable/api/Index.aspx) NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet is shown as a part of NodaTime library.

[image]

But I can't find it anywhere. Here's the NodeTime in ObjectBrowser in my VisualStudio.

[image]

I even looked into NodeTime.Testing and haven't found it.

[image]

I don't know where to look for it anymore. These two (NodeTime and NodeTime.Testing) are only packages available over NuGet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the page you linked to:

> Code in this namespace is not currently included in Noda Time NuGet packages; it is still deemed "experimental". To use these serializers, please download and build the Noda Time source code from the [project home page](http://noda-time.googlecode.com/).

For 1.2, we'll be distributing a separate pre-built assembly and NuGet package, but that's not quite ready yet, so for now you'll have to build your own.